# Redshift with Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, amazon-redshift

I have a Kafka - Spark Streaming application to ingest and process 60K  events per min. I need a database to store my transformed dataframes to be accessed by visualization layer. Can Redshift be used for this with Spark Streaming or should Cassandra be used? I will be processing and storing the dataframes in every spark window of 30 seconds. Also I need to read from the datastore in every window. I guess Redhsift is primarily a data warehousing database not for OLTP sort of the processing.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [SnappyData](https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata). SnappyData deeply integrates an in-memory database with Spark that allows hybrid OLTP/OLAP applications. You can write Spark Streaming applications on top of Snappy that can update/delete data from the database. Further, because it does not go over a connector, it [performs better](http://www.snappydata.io/blog/snappydata-memsql-cassandra-a-performance-benchmark) than [the myriad datastores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650298/how-to-save-insert-each-dstream-into-a-permanent-table/39753976#39753976) that have Spark connectors and even the native Spark cache. There may be other datastores that offer hybrid OLTP/OLAP applications on Spark in the aforementioned link.

Disclaimer: I am a SnappyData employee.