# External Lookup Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have a stream of data coming in from mysql table to kafka to my spark program.When a new row is inserted, I do transformations on the stream and save to cassandra.

My problem is when a row is updated, I would like to union the transformations I made previously when the row was created and the new update. I understand that I have the option of using stateful streaming and database connectors, can someone explain any other options I have when I need to perform an external look up.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're asking how to handle data mutations in Spark Streaming in addition to structured streaming?

For external look-ups, there are a wide variety of datastores available to use in conjunction with Spark. I created a sort of master list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39753976/3723346) awhile ago. As far as I know, [SnappyData](https://www.snappydata.io/) is the only one that allows you to perform data mutations *in a DataFrame itself*.

Disclaimer: I work for SnappyData

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @plambre! I will surely have a look.